# How to manually perform action for UITextField editing changed observed with rx?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I simply added two observables:

```
    mainView.textField.rx.text.orEmpty.bind(to: viewModel.searchPhrase).disposed(by: bag)
    mainView.textField.rx.controlEvent(.editingChanged).asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
       print("voilala")
    }).disposed(by: bag)
```

Now I would like to call actions from code to perform subscriptions and binding. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
view.textField.insertText("someText")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Reactive.text` is a `ControlProperty`, so it's both `ObserverType` and an `ObservableType` (at least in RxSwift 5.0).

It means that you can bind it either way. To read, like you already do:

```swift
mainView.textField.rx.text.orEmpty.bind(to: viewModel.searchPhrase).disposed(by: bag)
```

...or to write:

```swift
viewModel.searchPhrase.bind(to: mainView.textField.rx.text).disposed(by: bag)
```

**Edit:**
Obviously, you don't have to bind to edit text. You can perform a one time update with:

```swift
mainView.textField.rx.text.onNext("someText")
```

Comment: You will not get stucked in an infinite loop because binding to mainView.textField.rx.text doesn't trigger a control event

Comment: Guys, I think that you misunderstood the question;) I ask what to do in code to manually perform binding or observing blocks?

Comment: IMHO, you should rather modify value in your model (which is binded to your view) rather than programmatically editing value in your view and then observing view to update model. Personally, I would rather bind `viewModel.searchPhrase` and `mainView.textField` two way and then `viewModel.searchPhrase.onNext("someText")`

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is "don't do that." Whatever trigger is supposed to cause your "voilala" to print should be merged into the source so you don't feel the need to use your view as part of your model.

If you are merely trying to test some input, then you can trigger a control event the same you trigger any UIControl event with `sendAction(_:to:for:)` called on the textField itself.